# switch-based coroutines

Tags: c++, coroutine

I'm aware of an idiom or pattern for coroutines in C and C++:

```
struct cofunctor {
    int state = 0;

    void operator () () {
        switch ( state ) {
        case 0: // Caller must initialize to 0

            if ( bar1 ) return;

            while ( bar2 ) {
        state = 1; case 1:

                if ( bar3 ) return;

        state = 2; case 2:

                if ( bar4 ) return;
            }
        state = 3; case 3:
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

As the function executes, it updates a persistent checkpoint variable. The next time it's called, the value is used to jump into the middle of execution. In practice, the checkpoint would not be only an `int` but would contain "local" variables.

I'm writing in C++. My use-case seldom yields, so I'd like to update the checkpoints only during exception handling.

Is this pattern known in actual practice, or is it only documented as a curiosity? Does a reusable implementation exist in C++?

(As far as I can tell, Boost.Coroutine uses nonconforming stack hacks, not unlike `longjmp` multithreading. My application will seldom utilize coroutine control flow, and stack usage may be very high in the numerous "threads," so it is not amenable to such implementation.)

Comment: I think the thing I dislike the most about it is the fact that you have to keep the `state` yourself outside of the function.

Comment: `state = 0;` is never executed. Is it added for clarity?

Comment: The `barX`-variables are undefined. What is their meaning? Could you post a minimal working example? If `bar2 && !(bar3 || bar4)` you have an infinite loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Tobias `state = 0` is supposed to be initialization. Fixed. `barX` just stand in for random conditions. Likewise it's intended that something happens before the `if` statements.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Well, in C++ the state would just be nonstatic data members.

Comment: I was confused by the fact that you've used a reference. Anyway, stateful functors aren't really a novelty; a coroutine is just a special kind of a stateful functor.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Sorry, it's only pseudocode :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a reusable implementation exist in C++?

[This article](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/03/potted-guide-to-stackless-coroutines.html) also talks about a [one header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server4/coroutine.hpp), stackless implementation that resides inside the Boost.ASIO library.

[Another ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/coroutine.html) header seems to indicate that they've gone a step further from the previous state, but I do not know much about this one. It may be the same as the last or not.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Although ASIO's library isn't a perfect fit, now I see that the design space includes a variety of solutions and it's appropriate for me to roll my own, using similar techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it exists, is documented and used in well known and well distributed application (Putty, not C++ though).

- http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html

Another page about this use of Duff's device:

- http://research.swtch.com/duff

Duff even commented on this use saying he used it for interrupt driven state machine (what is now known under the buzz word "Async"):

- http://brainwagon.org/2005/03/05/coroutines-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

I implemented reusable stackful coroutines some time ago in standard C++, which allows you to have local variables (defined as members of coroutine classes). For calling a coroutine (I call it 'fiber' in my implementation) you first initialize a callstack object for containing the state and then start the coroutine. Here's an example how I define a coroutine:

```
struct fiber_func_test
{ PFC_FIBER_FUNC();
  // locals
  unsigned loop_count;
  // test function
  fiber_func_test(unsigned loops_): loop_count(loops_) {}
  bool tick(fiber_callstack &fc_, ufloat &dt_)
  {
    PFC_FIBER_BODY_BEGIN
    while(loop_count--)
    {
      PFC_FIBER_CALL(fc_, dt_, fiber_func_sleep, (0.3f));
    }
    PFC_FIBER_BODY_END
  }
};
```

loop_count is a local variable whose state is stored in the stack. And here's how it's called:

```
fiber_callstack fc;
PFC_FIBER_START(fc, fiber_func_test, (10));
while(fc.tick(0.1f))
  thread_nap();
```

Here's link to the code: http://sourceforge.net/p/spinxengine/code/HEAD/tree/sxp_src/core/mp/mp_fiber.h

Cheers, Jarkko

Answer (score 0):

boost.coroutine does not hack the stack - it uses simply the calling convention of the underlying calling convention (defined by the ABI).
You can say that it is simply a function call + store/restore the instruction and stack pointer.
Local variables are preserved automatically.

Comment: "Store/restore the instruction and stack pointer" is not possible with C++ primitives. It may be working within the bounds of each ABI on the supported platforms, but that still counts as a hack from a portable C++ perspective.